# Not Showing banner only vibrate device when push notification received

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When I Send push notification, I am getting notification on device, but it is not getting displayed as banner in the lock screen or notification center on the iPhone. I have iOS 9 installed on my iPhone.

Following is my code.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    registerForPushNotifications(application)

    return true
}

func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication)
{

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{
    print("DEVICE TOKEN = \(deviceToken)")

    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length
    {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    print("tokenString: \(tokenString)")
    strDeviceToken = tokenString
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Error = \(error)")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
        print(userInfo)
    }
```

Comment: Did you checked notification style from device setting.

Comment: Add func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
        fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) method , check https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: i am implement this method. but i am not getting banner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i am resolve this issue. their issue on php code not in iOS code. in php code they are missing **alert** Keyword in **aps** array that why device only vibrate when receive Notification.

Comment: for me it was the *body* keyword. It was present, but had an empty string. This apparently works for iOS 11 but not for iOS 10.

Comment: @gebirgsbärbel this is also true for Firebase cloud function push sending. For ios10 you have to put "body" and it should not be nil or "". For ios11 it doesn't matter.

Comment: please check this url in this you can check payload format https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure, your app is in background, or closed**, otherwise Push Notification Messages won't be visible on Screen. When app is running in foreground, iOS directly passes push Notification message to host app, without showing it on Home screen or Notification Screen.

> When your app is frontmost, UIKit delivers local and remote
>   notifications directly to your app delegate object without displaying
>   any system UI. UIKit calls the
>   application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method for incoming local
>   notifications and the
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
>   method for incoming remote notifications. Use the provided
>   notification dictionary to update your app accordingly. Because your
>   app is running, you can incorporate the notification data quietly or
>   update your user interface and let the user know that new information
>   is available.

Comment: Application close. i received notification but  no alert display on screen only device vibrate.